# apt-get -s E: the option « s » in command line [origin -s] is unknown

Tags: command-line, apt

Near all is in the title, but 14.04. I also tried all the 5 equivalent long (--) options found in man with the same error. -u from man also fails the same way. Please what is this? Thank you.

Comment: you have to add `install` option also. You command should be `sudo apt-get -s install package`

Comment: @rinzwind "-s, --simulate, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon, --no-act
    No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not actually change the system. 
Configuration Item: APT::Get::Simulate.
Simulate prints out a series of lines, each one representing an rpm
    operation: Configure (Conf), Remove (Remv), Unpack (Inst). Square brackets indicate broken packages with an empty set of square brackets meaning breaks that are of no consequence (rare)."

Comment: @useful What is the exact command you are typing? Should be something like `apt-get -s install gearhead`

Comment: @useful ok but you are still missing a command :) -s is not a commandd but an option.

Comment: @bain & Avinash Raj, I run [sudo]apt-get -s update then according to your advises, thinking the -s option was incompatible with update (although I believe I used it before), I also tried -s install evince.... oooooops... I add synaptic opened :(

Comment: Bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1399037. Affecting me on Kubuntu 14.10 using apt "1.0.9.2ubuntu2 0".

Answer (score 2):

You can't just execute `sudo apt-get -s`.  You need to tell it to do something.

That being said, doing a `sudo apt-get update -s` produces the same error you mention:

```
$ sudo apt-get update -s
E: Command line option 's' [from -s] is not known.
```

However, a `sudo apt-get install -s` does not error-out.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -s
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-23 linux-headers-3.13.0-23-generic linux-image-3.13.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-23-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

I'm going to assume that the `-s` flag only works with some of the commands.  It is mentioned in the [Apt/Get Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto) wiki.  The example given is with `install`, and it doesn't explicitly say that it will work with any other action.

> Use the -s flag to simulate an action."sudo apt-get -s install
>   " will simulate installing the package showing you what
>   packages will be installed and configured.

Comment: -s MUST be typed-in before install or a compatible command. That said, yesterday update-manager refused to even propose evince and cups updates (synaptic closed at the time, if not a little sentence in the window reminds me it waits for synaptic to quit). Do you think sudo apt-get -s install evince may have unlock something? Because now update-manager updated evince and cups... thx guys

Comment: @useful edit made

Comment: I tried it (-s) with autoremove : no error

Comment: Also compatible with dist-upgrade